# Access isAuthenticated prop using Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I think this is a relatively easy problem, however, I'm getting a little confused using Redux. Basically I'm trying to create a PrivateRoute Component and I can't figure out how to access the isAuthenticated prop. Help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Path: `App.js`

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    store.dispatch(loadUser());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <Header />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/login">
              <ErrorBoundary>
                <LoginPage />
              </ErrorBoundary>
            </Route>

            <PrivateRoute path="/purchase_order">
              <p>Test</p>
            </PrivateRoute>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Path: `PrivateRoute`

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ children, ...rest }) => (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={({ location }) =>
          this.props.isAuthenticated ? (
            children
          ) : (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: '/login',
                state: {
                  from: location
                }
              }}
            />
          )
        }
      />
    );

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
      auth: state.auth
    });

    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done great, you also have structured the functional component very well for `PrivateRoute`, but there is a mistake while accessing the props, and using as `this.props.isAuthenticated`, first thing `this.props` is used only and only in class-based React component or you can use it as (`props.isAuthenticated` assumed that you have passed `isAutheticated prop` in `PrivateRoute` React functional component).

### Points you have done-

1. You have connected your global state to this PrivateRoute functional component.
2. You have structurally defined your PrivateRoute functional component.

Redux state -

```
state: {
  auth: {userId: 'ob2-51-hw-s124' // any random string based on your API},
  otherReducer: {...}
}
```

### Points to be done-

1. import `connect` from the `react-redux` module.
2. import `Route`, `Redirect` from the `react-router-dom` module.

## Final Code

> AppRouter.js

```
// module import
import LandingPage from '...';
import NotFoundPage from '...';
import DashBoardPage from '...';
import LoginPage from '...';


// React functional component that can be imported in App.js
const AppRouter = () => (
  <Router history={history}>
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <PublicRoute path="/" exact={true}>
          <LandingPage />
        </PublicRoute>
        <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard">
          <DashboardPage />
        </PrivateRoute>
        <PrivateRoute path="/login">
          <LoginPage />
        </PrivateRoute>
        <PublicRoute path="/help" >
          <HelpPage />
        </PublicRoute>
        <Route>
          <NotFoundPage />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
);
export default AppRouter;
```

---

> PrivateRoute.js

```
// module import
import React form 'react';
import { connect }  from 'react-redux';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';


// React functional PrivateRoute component
export const PrivateRoute = ({
  auth,
  children,
  ...rest
}) => {

  const isAuthenticated = !!auth.userId; // converting auth.userId(typeof string) to false/true(typeof boolean)

  return (
    <Route {...rest} component={(props) => (
        isAuthenticated ? (
            children
          ) : (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: '/login',
                state: {
                  from: props.location 
                }
              }}
            />
          )
      )} 
    />
  );
}


// redux connect
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  auth: state.auth
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

Comment: This isn't working. The component tries to load before redux has the state.  So it always Redirects. I've add a little more code. Please see update

Comment: @bp123 I didn't get it which component tries to load before `redux` has the state? Are you talking about the `auth` state(is not finished before your `PrivateRouter` component load ) in the `Redux` global state?
I have updated the answered code with some more code base, please see the updates.

Comment: I think I've figured it out. I've added `if (auth.isLoading) return null` to the privateRoute component and I've set `isLoading` within initialState to true.

Comment: Yes! @bp123, that's what exactly I just was going to mention that please, use spinner for loading state while Async Redux action(which is login action) is taking place.
Please have it as a reference, if you stuck again in something, [GitHub repo](https://github.com/YadavAnurag/react-expensify-app)

Answer (score 0):

Your `mapStateToProps` function shows that you put the `state.auth` value into the `auth` prop

You are using a function component, so there is no `this`.

So, assuming that isAuthenticated is a property of auth, then:

`rest.auth.isAuthenticated` otherwise: `rest.auth`

You can also destructure the auth from the props and get direct access to it. Since you don't need to pass it into the route.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ children, auth, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={({ location }) =>
      auth.isAuthenticated ? (
        children
      ) : (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: '/login',
            state: {
              from: location
            }
          }}
        />
      )
    }
  />
);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```